# Theoretical Questions are Broad or Opinion-Based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Related to: [Why aren't authoritarian governments overthrown sooner?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13739/why-arent-authoritarian-governments-overthrown-sooner)

The linked question is attracting some close votes, primarily for being too broad, but also opinion-based. The question appears adequately answerable from a political science perspective.

My impression is that question about a general thing ("authoritarian governments" vs fascist Italy)  receive these close votes fairly reliably. Why?

It seems to me the question has scope that can be answered by comparative politics research without much trouble (something I did to answer the question).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretical questions are not too broad or opinion-based.

It is not the theoretical nature of your question that makes it broad.  It's the open-endedness of it.

There could be many reasons why Authoritarian governments last as long as they do, and the reasons could be different for different cases.

Because of this, it is not feasible to compose a complete or mostly complete answer to such a question.  Another problem is that Answers can be valid for some scenarios but invalid for other scenarios, and we want to avoid questions that are polluted with too many potentially invalid answers.

---

That's not to say that I think your question is so broad that I must close it.  Politics is often a fuzzy science and if we're not willing to be a little flexible with these things, then a lot of the meaningful questions won't get asked.